# Unknown SQL Exception -1 occurred. OWSTIMER.exe for intermittently delayed alerts

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, timer-jobs, owstimer

I am currently troubleshooting our alerts system.  It seems to send alert emails intermittently with sometimes no delays or sometimes multi-hour delays.

I am poking around in the log files and the only critical ones I see are

Unknown SQL Exception -1 occurred. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.  A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
for

Process: OWSTIMER.EXE
EventID: 5586

I am trying to figure out what database setting it is actually trying to connect to ?  I can't tell from the error message what db connection is failing.

Comment: You can run `Set-SPLogLevel -TraceSeverity VerboseEx` to capture which database it is connecting to, but this is indicative of overall network connectivity issues between SharePoint and the SQL Server.

Comment: I guess which particular "setting" or setting screen should I look at to see which database it is trying to connect to ... we inherited this SP setup from someone who left :/

Comment: Wow - now the log file is growing massively - how do I reset it to defaults ?

Comment: `Clear-SPLogLevel`

Comment: I did this and a reboot, but it still seems to be making massive logs.  Anything else to try ?

Comment: Clear your config cache - https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Clear-Configuration-Cache-d55bcba9